# Apalike sort as it appears in text

Tags: citing, natbib, apa-style, amsart

I am currently using \documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}

I am currently using

```
 \bibliographystyle{apalike} 
        \bibliography{harry}
```

with

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

I want my references sorted by as they appear in text with numbers. However the references are sorted by alphabetical order.